# Corrupted python file

Tags: python

By mistake I have corrupted python file.

```
gauravv@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cp test.py /usr/local/bin/python
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/python’: Permission denied
gauravv@ubuntu:~/Documents$ sudo cp test.py /usr/local/bin/python
[sudo] password for gauravv: 
gauravv@ubuntu:~/Documents$
```

Now I am getting this error

```
gauravv@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ python
bash: /usr/local/bin/python: /usr/local/bin/python: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
gauravv@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$
```

Any way to restore this file w/o installation.

Comment: You replaced python interpreter with your test.py and now you want to restore it? No its not possible.

Comment: Copy it from another machine.

Comment: isn't it a question (like all your others) for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your distribution `/usr/local/bin/python` was probably just a link to the actual binary, which you can definitely restore. 
All you need to do is find the original binary. Look in places like `/usr/bin`.

Then restore the link:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Yes, that is correct because python was the symbolic link but my work has corrupted the actual file too.            gauravv@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ cat python2 |more
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
print(sys.platform)
print(2**100)
x='spam!'
print(x*8)
gauravv@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ cat python2.7 |more
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
print(sys.platform)
print(2**100)
x='spam!'
print(x*8)
gauravv@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$

Comment: If you have really overwritten the original binary, start your ubuntu version from a live cd and copy the python binary on a USB stick. Then boot into your installation and restore the file.

Comment: Thanks guys I got the python file from ubuntu default directory. After copy from there it is working now.